# How to stop JMH benchmarks?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

Let us assume we are in the middle of a JMH benchmark and we find that something is wrong. For example there is no required resource or something wrong just happens.

1. What is a correct way to **stop all measurements** and benchmarks? Is calling `System.exit(...)` with no zero argument the only choice?
2. What if we want to abort only the current benchmark but continue with others?

Comment: did you read [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2016-September/002333.html) by any chance?

Comment: @Eugene I can see from the link that every test thread is checking `isDone` flag under the hood. When I make every test thread finish operation by throwing something and every thread is daemon thread the whole JMH benchmark stops (but I need to achieve this on my own way) . I don't see any built-in mechanism to stop everything from one test operation (besides `System.exit(..)`)

Comment: well stopping an individual one is easy, you can have a `@TearDown` method, but to stop them all you could use `.shouldFailOnError(true)`. `System.exit` is not going to help as usually the tests are run in forked VMs.

Comment: I found that one of created thread from QuickFix/J was not a daemon thread and this caused the test to run forever. Setting of `shouldFailOnError(true)` did not help for this case. I needed to check in my program that something wrong happen (by catching Exceptions in the test) and stop the QF/J thread manually. 
What I expect is that if there is an exception from test method (and there are no active test worker threads) the JMH framework  should stop tested JVM. Because it creates new JVM processes it should have full control of after if I specify `shouldFailOnError(true)` .

Comment: Maybe there should be another flag `.interruptAllThreadsAfterTest(true)` to this above for compatibility reasons. After all test workers finish and after give some time for not daemon threads to shutdown, JMH can interrupt remaining threads and wait for join .

Or am I missing something, maybe ?

Comment: @Eugene `@TearDown` was not called in my case -  `.shouldFailOnError(true)`; all test worker threads finish with an Exception and there is a not daemon thread .

Comment: you need to provide a minimal verifiable example here. Whatever I said above, I tested it before posting, but it might be that your set-up is very different. If you can't help us, we can't help you

Comment: When I run my benchmark it runs forever, how do I make it stop? I have used @Benchmark
 @Fork(value = 5, warmups = 2). Thank You.